# How to set default route in Ocelot

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, api-gateway, ocelot

I have created a separate ASP.NET Core Web API using Ocelot. The project will act as API gateway for other services.

What should be the configuration to call controllers (action methods) in API gateway project itself.

The above mentioned need arises when the project is hosted in Docker. I wanted to check if its hosted correctly so I tried to hit https://localhost:7143/api/index Or https://localhost:6001/api/index  but it didn't work.

```
{
  "Routes": [      
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Category/add",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 9100
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/category/add",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "post" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {

        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseURL": "https://localhost:6001"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ocelot describes the routing of one request to another as a Route, takes incoming HTTP requests and forward them on to a downstream service. The `UpstreamPath`Template defines the URL of the API Gateway that receives the requests and then redirects to the microservice API (`DownstreamPathTemplate`). What's default route ? Do you want to define the order you want your Routes to match the Upstream HttpRequest by including a Priority property in ocelot.json ?

Comment: The ocelot is implemented in Api gateway project [.net core web api]). I want to hit the controllers present in project itself. In my case I want to call index controller as described in screenshot. And as long as routing is concerned its working fine.

Comment: *"...but it didn't work."* - in what way did it not work? What is the behavior you are seeing and how does that differ from what you expect to see?

Comment: '''page cannot be found'''.